# Angular increment variable in ng-for

Tags: javascript, angular, wow.js

I am looping on a list of links with `ng-for`. Using a plugin called `wowjs` their icons are supposed to appear each one with a different duration. The first appears the fastest, the last one appears the latest.

In order to make this work, you need to set the `data-wow-delay` attribute to a duration in seconds. I.e "1.0s".

I created a variable `dataWowDelay` that I set to 1.0, and then I concatenate `'s'`. The issue is that I am trying to increment this variable after each loop of the `ng-for` but this does not work before of a parse error.

```
<ul class="social-list">
  <li *ngFor="let link of links">
    <a class="wow zoomIn" [attr.data-wow-delay]="dataWowDelay + 's'">
       <span></span>
    </a>
    {{ dataWowDelay = dataWowDelay + 0.1 }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already an iterator index you can use for this very simply:

```
<ul class="social-list">
  <li *ngFor="let link of list; let idx = index">
    <a class="wow zoomIn" [attr.data-wow-delay]="idx * 0.01 + 's'">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note the use of the `index` here; simply use your multiplier and this will work fine.

Comment: Whooo! Amazing!